# Add header line to koma script (scrbook) list of figures and change line spacing

Tags: spacing, koma-script, scrbook, header

I've been writing with the scrbook class in KOMA Script and I can't figure out how to change the formatting for my list of figures.

My school has specific style guidelines for theses. For my list of figures (and my list of tables) I need to format as follows:

- The word “Table” or “Figure” (when creating a List of Figures) is placed double (left aligned) spaced above the first Table/Figure caption.
- The word “Page” is placed double spaced and right aligned above the page reference column.
- Double space between captions.
- Always single space between the lines of a multi-line Table/Figure caption.

I've looked through the KOMA Scripts documentation, but I don't see any options to add a header line or change line spacing. Many of my figures have multi-line captions and I'd rather not change them. This is also the last thing I have to do with this document, so I don't want to use a different class.

How do I add the words "Figure" and "Page" to the top of the list?

And how do I change the spacing between captions to double-spaced but leave the spacing between lines in a caption as single-spaced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunaly there is no MWE (minimal working example) in your question. But maybe you want something like

```latex
\documentclass[listof=nochaptergap]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\AfterTOCHead[lof]{\noindent\figurename\hfill Page\par}
\AfterTOCHead[lot]{\noindent\tablename\hfill Page\par}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  beforeskip=\baselineskip,
  indent=0pt
  ]{default}{figure,table}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{Foo}
\captionof{figure}{Figure in first chapter}
\captionof{table}{Table in first chapter}
\captionof{figure}{\blindtext}
\captionof{table}{\blindtext}
\chapter{Bar}
\captionof{figure}{Figure in second chapter}
\captionof{figure}{\blindtext}
\captionof{table}{Table in second chapter}
\captionof{table}{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had to change it slightly since I have an older version of KOMA Script installed. \DeclareTOCStyleEntries was unrecognized, so I had to use use \DeclareTOCStyleEntry twice. Also, this wasn't part of my original question, but how can I make the words "Figure", "Table", and "Page" bold in the header?

Comment: `\AfterTOCHead[lof]{\noindent\textbf{\figurename}\hfill \textbf{Page}\par}`